# react routes not functioning and rendering proper component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am currently working on  a page which has /users as url and has rendered one component .In this page I need a link which takes me to /roles and I did the following  in the users components

```
<li><Link to="/roles">{data.firstName}</Link></li>
```

After linking here , i added a route for '/roles in my routers but still it doesn't seem to be working .
Here is the router part .

```
<Router>


 <Switch>
                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                <PrivateRoute  path='/users' component={OrganizationUser} />
                <PrivateRoute path='/' component={Organization} />
                <PrivateRoute path='/home' component={Home} />
                <PrivateRoute path ='/roles' component={Home1} />

            </Switch>
        </Router>
```

What i see is that on '/roles',I still get Organization rendered on screen instead of Home1.

Comment: From the [react-router docs on <Switch>](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch/children-node): "Only the first child to match the current location will be rendered". So '/' will be used for any route other than '/login' or '/users'. If you re-arrange the routes so that '/'is last it should work.

Comment: Thank you for saving my life .I did not remember this .

Comment: Use exact in root route

Answer (score 0):

when router see `path=/` use this and because this route comes before `/role` then render it, so just rearrange the routes like this :

```
 <Switch>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <PrivateRoute  path='/users' component={OrganizationUser} />
            <PrivateRoute path='/home' component={Home} />
            <PrivateRoute path ='/roles' component={Home1} />
            <PrivateRoute path='/' component={Organization} />


        </Switch>
```

if you dont want to rearrage you can add `exact` properto to `path=/` like this

```
<Switch>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <PrivateRoute  path='/users' component={OrganizationUser} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={Organization} />
            <PrivateRoute path='/home' component={Home} />
            <PrivateRoute path ='/roles' component={Home1} />

        </Switch>
```